# Need to convert a query into Eloquent Model laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have a query of MySQL but I need to convert it into an eloquent model laravel 8. The query is given below,

```
$query = "SELECT  group_id FROM `chat_histories` join chat_group on chat_group.id = chat_histories.group_id where chat_group.is_group = 1 and chat_histories.created_at BETWEEN '$startDate' and '$endDate' and chat_histories.deleted_at is null group by group_id";
$query = "select count(group_id) as total_chat_thread from ($query) total_chat";
DB::select($query);
```

So far i have done this,

```
ChatHistory::leftJoin('chat_group', 'chat_group.id', '=', 'chat_histories.group_id')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as totals')
        ->where('chat_group.is_group', 1)
        ->whereBetween('chat_histories.created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->groupBy('chat_histories.group_id')
        ->count('totals');
```

But this returns a list, but I need that count of the list. That means it's showing 22 rows, I need that 22 as return.

My Model ChatHistory relation with ChatGroup

```
 public function chatGroup() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ChatGroup::class, 'group_id', 'id');
}
```

My Model ChatGroup relation with ChatHistory

```
public function chatHistory() {
    return $this->hasMany(ChatHistory::class,'group_id','id');
}
```

Please help to convert it into an eloquent model query
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add your models code first, with the relations declared

Comment: please check the question, i have edited my question and added what have i done so far.

Comment: Did you get it to work with the answer below ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the model Group with a relation `history` hasMany. it should be like this.

```
$groupCount = ChatGroup::whereHas('chatHistory', function ($historyQB) use($startDate,$endDate)  {
    $historyQB->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->whereNull('deleted_at');
})->count();
```

You dont need the `whereNull`, if the model ChatHistory has softDelete enabled.

Comment: ChatHistory::leftJoin('chat_group', 'chat_group.id', '=', 'chat_histories.group_id')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as totals')
        ->where('chat_group.is_group', 1)
        ->whereBetween('chat_histories.created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->groupBy('chat_histories.group_id')
        ->count('totals');

But this returns a list, but I need that count of the list. That means it's showing 22 rows, I need that 22 as return.

Comment: @Md.Ashrafuzzaman i've edited the answer with what you added to your question, just run it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using Models, it would be much easier/cleaner

Something like that should work

```
DB::table('chat_histories')->select('group_id')->join('chat_group', 'chat_group.id', 'chat_histories.group_id')->where('chat_groups.is_group', 1)->whereBetween('chat_histories.created_at', $startDate, $endDate)->whereNull('chat_histories.deleted_at')->groupBy('group_id')->count();
```